# Logic apps- Post a choice of options as the flow bot to group chat

Tags: post, microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I can see that logic app has Microsoft teams "Post a choice options as the Flow bot to a user" action. However, I would like something where I can present options to a group chat or channel. The reason for not sending multiple individual messages are because I would like only 1 person to response in first come first serve kind of way.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
I can see that logic app has Microsoft teams "Post a choice option as the Flow bot to a user
```

Yes, you can use Post a choice of options as the flow bot to a user connector in logic Apps to present options to a user as shown in below images.
[image]
[image]

[image]

```
I would like something where I can present options to a group chat or channel.
```

But if you want to present options to a group chat or channel AFAIK there is no such built-in connector available in logic Apps. You can achieve this using Adaptive cards.

Adaptive cards for [Microsoft teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/overview-adaptive-cards)

By following this [document](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/botframework-reactive-adaptive-cards-how-to-read-data-on-action-buttons-in-adap2/), you can add radio buttons or by changing test as an option you can create buttons labeled option1 and option2 as per your requirement.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
       {
      "type": "Text Block",
      "text": "Please select an option:"
       }
    ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Option 1",
      "data": {
        "id": "option1"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Option 2",
      "data": {
        "id": "option2"
      }
    },
    
    
      
    
  ]
}
```

[image]

Reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/teams/send-a-message-in-teams)